# Why do I get this merge conflict with git rebase interactive?

Tags: git, rebase

I'm still learning git.

I have a file called `names.txt`. With this text.

[image]

This is my commit history

[image]

The first commit added the file.
The second commit added the first line Mary.
The third commit added the second line John.

```
git show 7bdb5ef
```

[image]

```
git show 80384aa
```

[image]

I want to rebase this and edit the commit Mary to change the text to `Mary Shelly`.

```
I do git rebase -i 4a5244b
```

Next I set commit Mary to edit and run the rebase.

[image]

Rebase stops here.

[image]

Now name.txt has the value at Mary commit.
[image]

I change it to `Mary Shelly` and stage it.

I run

```
git commit --amend
```

followed by

```
git rebase --continue
```

Now I get this merge conflict.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why this happens. Commit `John` only changes the second line in the file. When we edit the commit `Mary` we only change the first line of the file. 
How does this cause a conflict?

Comment: I believe it has to do with blobs not being a 1:1 mapping to text file lines, but I don't understand well enough to explain it as an answer. Read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Remember that while a commit is *displayed* as a diff from its parents, it's really a full *snapshot* of the code at the time of the commit. Your third commit doesn't simply add "John" to whatever was there before, it is *specifically* the two lines "Mary" and "John". Now you are rebasing that on top of "Mary Shelly", and Git can't determine if it should change "Mary Shelly" back to "Mary", or keep "Mary Shelly".

Comment: @chepner how I learned is that git remembers lines of code. And the commits Mary and John modify two different lines of code. When you `revert` a commit, you are said to revert the changes made in that particular commit. If a commit is just a full snapshot of the code how do we even know what changes are recorded in which commits? Is this referenced in any documentation I can study?

Comment: It's a result of the three-way merge algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control) for more details).

Comment: (Indeed, `revert` has to first compute a diff between the commit to be reverted and its parent, then apply that diff to the currently checked-out commit in order to create the new commit.)

Comment: (Packfiles, which Git will use to save space by storing just deltas between versions, complicate matters a little. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there *is* a merge conflict, and [chepner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) is the key to understanding why.  Well, that, and the *commit graph*, plus the fact that `git rebase` consists of repeated `git cherry-pick` operations.  Interactive rebase allows you to add your own commands between each `git cherry-pick`, or even change the cherry-picks to something else.  (The initial command-sheet starts out as all-`pick` commands, each of which means *do a cherry-pick*.)

Your commit history is a summary of your commit graph—essentially, the result of visiting each commit *in* the commit graph, starting at some particular ending point (the tip of your current branch) and working backwards.  If you use `git log --graph` you get some potentially-important information that is left out without `--graph`, although in this particular case, it's easy to see that the graph is linear.  So you just have three commits:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

where `A` is actually `4a5244b`, `B` stands for `7bdb5ef`, and `C` stands for `80384aa` (if I've transcribed the images correctly).  Each commit has a full, complete copy of the file `names.txt`.  The copy is of course *different* in commits `A`, `B`, and `C`, in that in `A`, it's empty; in `B`, it is one line reading `Mary`; and in `C`, it is two lines reading `Mary` and then `John`

The graph itself arises from the fact that commit `C`, or `80384aa`, contains the hash ID of commit `B`, or `7bdb5ef`, *inside `C` itself*.  That's why I drew an arrow coming out of `C` pointing to `B`.  Git calls this `C`'s *parent* commit.  Git records `C`'s hash ID in the name `master`, and then attaches the special name `HEAD` *to* the name `master`, so that it knows that this is where `git log` should start, and that commit `C` is the one you have out, for working-on, right now.

When you run `git rebase -i 4a5244b`—choosing commit `A` as the new base—Git figures out that this means *copy commits `B` and `C`*, so it puts their hash IDs into the list of `pick` commands.  It then opens your editor on the command-sheet.  You change `pick` to `edit`, which tells Git: *Do the cherry-pick, then exit the rebase, in the middle of the operation.*

You didn't *force* rebase to make a true copy.  (To do that, use `-f` or `--no-ff` or `--force-rebase`—all mean the same thing.  It doesn't really matter here, nor in most cases.)  So Git saw that there was an instruction, *Copy `B` so that it comes after `A`*, and realized: *Hey, wait, `B` is already after `A`.  I'll just leave it there.*  Git did that and stopped, leaving you in this state:

```
A--B   <-- HEAD
    \
     C   <-- master
```

Note that `HEAD` is no longer attached to `master`: it now points directly to commit `B`.  Commit `C` remains, and `master` still points to it, but Git has stopped in "detached HEAD" mode to allow you to do your edit.

You make your change to the file, `git add`, and `git commit --amend`.  This makes a *new* commit—we could call it `B'` or `D`, and usually I use `B'` since usually it's a whole lot like `B`, but this time it's different enough, so let's use `D`.  The new commit has `A` as its parent—that's what `--amend` does.  Git updates `HEAD` to point to the new commit.  Existing commit `B` remains intact.  So now you have:

```
  D   <-- HEAD
 /
A--B
    \
     C   <-- master
```

The file `names.txt` in `D` has the new single line reading `Mary Shelly`.

You now run `git rebase --continue`, so Git continues with what's left in the instruction sheet.  That consists of `pick <hash-of-C>`, which makes Git run `git cherry-pick` to copy `C`.  This copy needs to go after the current commit, `D`.  Existing commit `C` doesn't, so Git has to really do the job this time.

#### A cherry-pick is a merge—merge as a verb, at least

To perform a merge operation—*to merge*, the action—Git needs three inputs.  These three inputs are the *merge base* commit, the current or `--ours` commit (also sometimes called *local*, particularly by `git mergetool`), and the other or `--theirs` commit (sometimes called *remote*).  For regular merges, the base is often a bit distant: it's where the two lines of commits diverged.  For cherry-pick—and for revert, for that matter—the base is right next to the commit.  The merge base of this operation is `C`'s parent commit `B`!

The actual operation of merge consists of running two `git diff` commands on the entire commits:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-base hash-of-ours`: what did we change?
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-base hash-of-theirs`: what did they change?

So Git now diffs commit `B`, the base, vs commit `D`, your current/ours commit.  That diff affects file `names.txt` and says: *change the one line that says Mary to two lines: one reading Mary Shelly, and one reading John.*  Then Git diffs `B` vs `C`, to see what "they" (you, earlier) did.  The diff affects file `names.txt` and says: *add the line reading John at the end of the file, after the line reading Mary.*

That's what Git shows you in the merge-conflict section: one file says *replace Mary with Mary Shelly*, the other says *keep Mary and add John*.  If you like, you can tell Git to keep, in the merge-conflict section, more information.  To do this, set `diff.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.  (The default, if it's not set, is `merge`.)

With the `diff3` setting, you'll see that the *base* content—marked by `|||||||`—is the one line `Mary`, and that the two files from the conflicting commits have replaced that base with, respectively, either `Mary Shelly` or `Mary` + new line `John`.  I find this kind of merge conflict clearer and easier to merge manually.

In any case, your job at this point is to come up with the correct result—whatever that is—and write that out and copy it into index slot zero.  Typically you'll just edit the messy `names.txt` that Git left in your work-tree, put the right contents into it, and then run `git add names.txt`.

#### Resuming

Having fixed the conflict, run `git whatever --continue` to resume whatever operation stopped—in this case, rebase, but this happens with cherry-pick and merge as well.  Git will use the index contents, which you updated with `git add`, to make the new commit that's a copy of `C`:

```
  D--C'   <-- HEAD
 /
A--B
    \
     C   <-- master
```

Having reached the end of the command sheet, `git rebase` now finishes up by yanking the name `master` off commit `C` and pasting it onto `C'`, which is the last copy it made, and then re-attaching `HEAD`:

```
  D--C'   <-- master (HEAD)
 /
A--B
    \
     C   [abandoned]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :)

Comment: I had a conflict when squashing a linear sequence of git commits with interactive rebase. Now it is clear to me why that could happen – I've used `git rebase -i HEAD~25` which included the commits I wanted to squash, but also others which I ignored and I thought git would ignore too … and these were branching.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster: note that modern `git rebase -i` now understands, and can re-perform, merges when using `--rebase-merges`. This should not be run without first understanding exactly what it does, though (well, we can say that about much of Git  which is sometimes especially unfortunate for newbies...).

Comment: @torek Finally gave it a try today, looks very useful!

Answer (score 0):

File-level merge operations (i.e. operations during which Git needs to reconcile two sets of changes to a file) try to allow you to move code around without causing too many conflicts, so in order to try and find the right place to apply a change, the *context* - the set of surrounding lines - is factored in, too.

Here, re-applying the commit `John` causes trouble: the original commit added `John` next to a line `Mary`. Now Git is trying to re-apply the commit but that reference line saying `Mary` no longer exists - all that's there is a line saying `Mary Shelly`... keep in mind that Git doesn't understand the purpose and/or meaning of your file, so in a case like this it won't take any chances and present this to you as a conflict so you can check it over.

Try the same thing again with a lot of other lines between `John` and `Mary` which you'll be keeping the same - you'll see that you won't get a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the change you made to the original line is in practice too likely to also be needed on the added adjacent line to allow the merge to succeed without getting human judgement involved. The example I use is

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if ( g->tag == mark 
      || g->tag == error ) {
||||||||||||||
    if ( tag == mark
      || tag == error ) {
==============
    if ( tag == mark 
      || tag == release
      || tag == error ) {
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

where one change added `g->` to a pair of lines and another change added the `release` line in the middle.