# What it means "changes introduced by a commit" in git

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Everywhere I see this: "...cherry-pick applies changes introduced by a commit..."

I did this: created this file in master:

```
** File 1 **

Content

** Footer **
```

then branched out to branch2 and committed a change:

```
** File 1 **

Content
Edit 1

** Footer **
```

and then another one:

```
** File 1 **

Content
Edit 2
Edit 1

** Footer **
```

Now I went back to master and tried to cherry-pick the latest commit from branch2. I expected that only 'Edit2' will get imported since isn't this a change introduced by that commit, compared to the previous one?

What I got instead is the following merge conflict:

```
** File 1 **

Content
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
Edit 2
Edit 1
>>>>>>> b634e53...
** Footer **
```

Now my obvious question is what is it that I misunderstand about how cherry-pick works, and concretely why there is a merge conflict here, which would be a fast-forward with git merge?

IMPORTANT NOTICE: This is NOT meant as a question about merge conflicts, what I'm interested in is what cherry-pick is actually doing here. And I'm not asking from curiosity/whatever, but because I'm running into troubles using git on my job.

Comment: This is a fairly common type of question here.  Git has an algorithm for when changes made by two different branches (commits really) register as a merge conflict.  Because the changes introduced in the second branch are in close proximity to the original content, therefore Git is flagging it as a merge conflict.

Comment: Hm, I can't say I understand this... What actually bugs me is whether cherry-pick considers only the diff a commit introduced compared with the previous one or it does something else?

Comment: For safety, it looks for a matching context, and if you remove the first commit in the branch, it sees that the line before the change is different; and so it is rejected as unsafe, so you can review and override manually. You can change this with an option. Again, this is a common FAQ; did you search before asking?

Comment: You can look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852116/how-does-exactly-a-git-merge-conflict-happen) to get more details about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does exactly a git merge conflict happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852116/how-does-exactly-a-git-merge-conflict-happen)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do cherry-pick and revert work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572096/how-do-cherry-pick-and-revert-work)

Comment: Thanks phd, the link contains the answer I was seaching for. Cherry-pick does a specific three-way merge, and not patch application as I have thought.

Comment: What do you know of commits and what they are? If so, a cherry pick copies a commit from one parent to another.

Comment: I'd say that this kind of questions are not really for stack-overflow... However I was forced to try because existing books tend to be ambiguous on Git details. Thanks everyone for your answers, they were helpful.

Comment: @evolutionxbox `cherry-pick` doesn't copy commits because commits in git contain the full tree of files and `cherry-pick` doesn't copy these files. `cherry-pick` **calculates changes** introduced by a commit comparing it to the previous commit and **applies these changes** with 3-way merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As several people have noted in comments (and made links to other questions), `git cherry-pick` actually does a three way merge.  [How do cherry-pick and revert work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34572096/1256452) describes this, but more in terms of content than mechanism.

I describe the source of a particular *set* of merge conflicts in [Why do I get this merge conflict with git rebase interactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54829847/1256452), along with a general outline of cherry-pick and revert, but I think it's a good idea to step back and ask the *mechanism* question you did.  I would re-frame it a bit, though, as these three questions:

- Is a commit really a snapshot?
- If a commit is a snapshot, how does `git show` or `git log -p` show it as a *change?*
- If a commit is a snapshot, how can `git cherry-pick` or `git revert` work?

Answering the last requires first answering one more question:

- How does Git perform `git merge`?

So, let's take these four questions, in the correct order.  This is going to be rather long, and if you like, you can jump straight to the last section—but note that it builds on the third section, which builds on the second, which builds on the first.

## Is a commit really a snapshot?

Yes—though, technically, a commit *refers to* a snapshot, rather than *being* one.  This is pretty simple and straightforward.  To use Git, we generally start out by running `git clone`, which gets us a new repository.  Occasionally, we start out by making an empty directory and using `git init` to create an *empty* repository.  Either way, though, we now have three entities:

1. The repository itself, which a big database of *objects*, plus a smaller database of *name to hash ID mappings* (for, e.g., branch names), plus lots of other mini-databases implemented as single files (e.g., one per reflog).
2. Something Git calls the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*.  What it gets called depends on who does the calling.  The index is essentially where you have Git build the *next* commit you will make, though it takes on an expanded role during merges.
3. The *work-tree*, which is where you can actually see files and work on / with them.

The object database holds four types of objects, which Git calls *commits*, *trees*, *blobs*, and *annotated tags*.  Trees and blobs are mostly implementation detail, and we can ignore annotated tags here: the main function of this big database, for our purposes, is to hold all our commits.  These commits then refer to the trees and blobs that hold the files.  In the end, it's actually the combination of trees-plus-blobs that is the snapshot.  Still, every commit has exactly one tree, and that tree is what gets us the rest of the way to the snapshot, so except for lots of devilish implementation details, the commit itself might as well be a snapshot.

#### How we use the index to make *new* snapshots

We won't go too deep into the weeds yet, but we will say that the index works by holding a compressed, Git-ified, mostly-frozen copy of every file.  Technically, it holds a *reference to* the actually-frozen copy, stored as a *blob*.  That is, if you start by doing `git clone url`, Git has run `git checkout branch` as the last step of the clone.  This `checkout` filled-in the index from the commit at the tip of *branch*, so that the index has a copy of every file in that commit.

Indeed, most<sup>1</sup> `git checkout` operations fill in *both* the index *and* the work-tree from a commit.  This lets you see, and use, all of your files in the work-tree, but the work-tree copies aren't the ones that are actually *in* the commit.  What's in the commit is (are?) frozen, compressed, Git-ified, can-never-be-changed blob snapshots of all of those files.  This keeps those versions of those files forever—or for as long as the commit itself exists—and is great for archival, but useless for doing any actual work.  That's why Git de-Git-ifies the files into the work-tree.

Git *could* stop here, with just commits and work-trees.  Mercurial—which is in many ways like Git—*does* stop here: your work-tree is your proposed next commit.  You just change stuff in your work-tree and then run `hg commit` and it makes the new commit from your work-tree.  This has the obvious advantage that there's no pesky index making trouble.  But it also has some drawbacks, including being inherently slower than Git's method.  In any case, what Git does is to start with the *previous* commit's information *saved in* the index, ready to be committed again.

Then, each time you run `git add`, Git compresses and Git-ifies the file you add, and *updates the index now*.  If you change just a few files, and then `git add` just those few files, Git only has to update a few index entries.  So this means that *at all times* the index has the *next snapshot inside it*, in the special Git-only compressed and ready-to-freeze form.

This in turn means that `git commit` simply needs to freeze the index contents.  Technically, it turns the index into a new tree, ready for the new commit.  In a few cases, such as after some reverts, or for a `git commit --allow-empty`, the new tree will actually be the *same* tree as some previous commit, but you don't need to know or care about this.

At this point, Git collects your log message and the other metadata that goes into each commit.  It adds the current time as the time-stamp—this helps make sure that each commit is totally unique, as well as being generally useful.  It uses the *current* commit as the new commit's *parent* hash ID, uses the *tree* hash ID produced by saving the index, and writes out the new commit object, which gets a new and unique commit hash ID.  The new commit therefore contains the actual hash ID of whatever commit you had checked out earlier.

Last, Git writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name, so that the branch name now refers to the *new* commit, rather than to the new commit's parent, as it used to.  That is, whatever commit *was* the tip of the branch, now that commits is one step *behind* the tip of the branch.  The new tip is the commit you just made.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can use `git checkout commit -- path` to extract one particular file from one particular commit.  This *still* copies the file into the index first, so that's not really an exception.  However, you can also use `git checkout` to copy files just from the index, to the work-tree, and you can use `git checkout -p` to selectively, interactively *patch* files, for instance.  Each of these variants has its own special set of rules as to what it does with index and/or work-tree.

Since Git builds new commits *from* the index, it may be wise—albeit painful—to re-check the documentation often.  Fortunately, `git status` tells you a lot about what's in the index now—by comparing the current commit vs the index, then comparing the index vs the work-tree, and for each such comparison, telling you what's *different*.  So a lot of the time, you don't have to carry around, in your head, all the wildly varying details of each Git command's effect on index and/or work-tree: you can just run the command, and use `git status` later.

---

## How does `git show` or `git log -p` show a commit as a change?

Each commit contains the raw hash ID of its parent commit, which in turn means that we can always start at the *last* commit of some string of commits, and work *backwards* to find all the previous commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

We only need to have a way to find the *last* commit.  That way is: the *branch name*, such as `master` here, identifies the *last* commit.  If that last commit's hash ID is `H`, Git finds commit `H` in the object database.  `H` stores `G`'s hash ID, from which Git finds `G`, which stores `F`'s hash ID, from which Git finds `F`, and so on.

This is also the guiding principle behind showing a commit as a patch.  We have Git look at the commit itself, find its parent, and extract that commit's snapshot.  Then we have Git extract the commit's snapshot too.  Now we have two snapshots, and now we can compare them—subtract the earlier one from the later one, as it were.  Whatever is *different*, that must be what *changed* in that snapshot.

Note that this only works for *non-merge* commits.  When we have Git build a *merge* commit, we have Git store not one but *two* parent hash IDs.  For instance, after running `git merge feature` while on `master`, we may have:

```
       G--H--I
      /       \
...--F         M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \       /
       J--K--L   <-- feature
```

Commit `M` has *two* parents: its first parent is `I`, which *was* the tip commit on `master` just a moment ago.  Its second parent is `L`, which is still the tip commit on `feature`.  It's hard—well, impossible, really—to present commit `M` as a simple change from either `I` or `L`, and by default, `git log` simply *doesn't bother* to show any changes here!

(You can tell both `git log` and `git show` to, in effect, *split* the merge: to show a diff from `I` to `M`, and then to show a second, separate diff from `L` to `M`, using `git log -m -p` or `git show -m`.  The `git show` command produces, by default, what Git calls a *combined diff*, which is kind of weird and special: it's made by, in effect, running both diffs as for `-m`, then *ignoring most of what they say* and showing you only some of those changes that come from *both* commits.  This relates pretty strongly to how merges work: the idea is to show the parts that might have had merge conflicts.)

This leads us to our embedded question, which we need to cover before we get to cherry-pick and revert.  We need to talk about the mechanics of `git merge`, i.e., how we got a *snapshot* for commit `M` in the first place.

## How does Git perform `git merge`?

Let's start by noting that the *point* of a merge—well, of most merges, anyway—is to *combine work*.  When we did `git checkout master` and then `git merge feature`, we meant: *I did some work on `master`.  Someone else did some work on `feature`.  I'd like to combine the work they did with the work I did.*  There is a process for doing this combining, and then a simpler process for saving the result.

Thus, there are two parts to a true merge that results in a commit like `M` above.  The first part is what I like to call the *verb* part, *to merge*.  This part actually combines our different changes.  The second part is making *a merge*, or *a merge commit:* here we use the word "merge" as a noun or an adjective.

It's also worth mentioning here that `git merge` doesn't always make a merge.  The command itself is complicated and has lots of fun flag arguments to control it in various ways.  Here, we're only going to consider the case where it really does make an actual merge, because we're looking at merge in order to understand cherry-pick and revert.

#### Merge as a noun or adjective

The second part of a real merge is the easier part.  Once we've finished the *to merge* process, the merge-as-a-verb, we have Git make a new commit in the usual way, using whatever is in the index.  This means the index needs to end up with the merged content in it.  Git will build the tree as usual and collect a log message as usual—we can use the not-so-good default, `merge branch B`, or construct a good one if we're feeling particularly diligent.  Git will add our name, email address, and timestamp as usual.  Then Git will write out a commit—but instead of storing, in this new commit, just the *one* parent, Git will store an extra, *second* parent, which is the hash ID of the commit we chose when we ran `git merge`.

For our `git merge feature` while on `master`, for instance, the first parent will be commit `I`—the commit we had checked out by running `git checkout master`.  The second parent will be commit `L`, the one to which `feature` points.  That's really all there is to *a* merge: a merge commit is just a commit with at least two parents, and the standard two parents for a standard merge are that the first is the same as for *any* commit, and the second is the one we picked by running `git merge something`.

#### Merge as a verb

The merge-as-a-verb is the harder part.  We noted above that Git is going to make the *new* commit from whatever is in the index.  So, we need to put *into* the index, or have Git put into it, the result of *combining work*.

We declared above that we made some changes on `master`, and they—whoever they are—made some changes on `feature`.  But we already saw that Git doesn't *store* changes.  Git *stores* snapshots.  How do we go from *snapshot* to *change?*

**We already know the answer to that question!**  We saw it when we looked at `git show`.  Git *compares* two snapshots.  So for `git merge`, we just need to *pick the right snapshots*.  But which ones are the right snapshots?

The answer to *this* question lies in the commit graph.  Before we run `git merge`, the graph looks like this:

```
       G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
      /
...--F
      \
       J--K--L   <-- feature
```

We're sitting on commit `I`, the tip of `master`.  Their commit is commit `L`, the tip of `feature`.  From `I`, we can work backwards to `H` and then `G` and then `F` and then presumably `E` and so on.  Meanwhile, from `L`, we can work backwards to `K` and then `J` and then `F` and presumably `E` and so on.

When we *do* actually *do* this work-backwards trick, we *converge* at commit `F`.  Obviously, then, whatever changes we made, we started with the snapshot in `F` ... and whatever changes *they* made, they *also* started with the snapshot in `F`!  So all we have to do, to combine our two sets of changes, is:

- compare `F` to `I`: that's what we changed
- compare `F` to `L`: that's what they changed

We will, in essence, just have Git run two `git diff`s.  One will figure out what *we* changed, and one will figure out what *they* changed.  Commit `F` is our common starting point, or in version-control-speak, the *merge base*.

Now, to actually accomplish the merge, Git expands the index.  Instead of holding *one* copy of each file, Git will now have the index hold *three* copies of each file.  One copy will come from the merge base `F`.  A second copy will come from our commit `I`.  The last, third, copy comes from their commit `L`.

Meanwhile, Git also looks at the result of the two diffs, file-by-file.  As long as commits `F`, `I`, and `L` all have all the same files,<sup>2</sup> there are only these five possibilities:

1. Nobody touched the file.  Just use any version: they're all the same.
2. We changed the file and they didn't.  Just use our version.
3. They changed the file and we didn't.  Just use their version.
4. We and they both changed the file, but we made the *same* changes.  Use either ours or theirs—both are the same, so it doesn't matter which.
5. We and they both changed the *same* file, but we made *different* changes.

Case 5 is the only tough one.  For all the others, Git knows—or at least assumes it knows—what the right result is, so for all those other cases, Git shrinks the index slots for the file in question back to just one slot (numbered zero) that holds the correct result.

For case 5, though, Git stuffs all three copies of the three input files into three numbered slots in the index.  If the file is named `file.txt`, `:1:file.txt` holds the merge base copy from `F`, `:2:file.txt` holds our copy from commit `I`, and `:3:file.txt` holds their copy from `L`.  Then Git runs a low-level merge driver—we can set one in `.gitattributes`, or use the default one.

The default low-level merge takes the two diffs, from base to ours and from base to theirs, and tries to combine them by taking *both* sets of changes.  Whenever we touch *different* lines in the file, Git takes our or their change.  When we touch the *same* lines, Git declares a merge conflict.<sup>3</sup>  Git writes the resulting file to the work-tree as `file.txt`, with conflict markers if there were conflicts.  If you set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, the conflict markers include the *base* file from slot 1, as well as the lines from the files in slots 2 and 3.  I like this conflict style much better than the default, which omits the slot-1 context and shows just the slot-2 vs slot-3 conflict.

Of course, if there are conflicts, Git declares the merge conflicted.  In this case, it (eventually, after processing all the other files) stops in the middle of the merge, leaving the conflict-marker mess in the work-tree and all three copies of `file.txt` in the index, in slots 1, 2, and 3.  But if Git is able to resolve the two different change-sets on its own, it goes ahead and *erases* slots 1-3, writes the successfully-merged file to the work-tree,<sup>4</sup> copies the work-tree file into the index at the normal slot zero, and proceeds with the rest of the files as usual.

If the merge *does* stop, it is your job to fix the mess.  Many people do this by editing the conflicted work-tree file, figuring out what the right result is, writing out the work-tree file, and running `git add` to copy that file into the index.<sup>5</sup>  The copy-into-index step removes the stage 1-3 entries and writes the normal stage-zero entry, so that the conflict is resolved and we're ready to commit.  Then you tell the merge to continue, or run `git commit` directly since `git merge --continue` just runs `git commit` anyway.

This *to merge* process, while a bit complicated, is in the end pretty straightforward:

- Pick a merge base.
- Diff the merge base against the current commit, the one we have checked out that we're going to modify by merging, to see what *we* changed.
- Diff the merge base against the *other* commit, the one we picked to merge, to see what *they* changed.
- Combine the changes, applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot in the *merge base*.  That's the result, which goes in the index.  It's OK that we start out with the merge base version, because the *combined* changes *include* our changes: we won't lose them *unless* we say *take only their version of the file*.

This *to merge* or *merge as a verb* process is then followed by the *merge as noun* step, making a merge commit, and the merge is done.

---

<sup>2</sup>If the three input commits *don't* have all the same files, things get tricky.  We can have add/add conflicts, modify/rename conflicts, modify/delete conflicts, and so on, all of which are what I call *high level* conflicts.  These also stop the merge in the middle, leaving slots 1-3 of the index populated as appropriate.  The `-X` flags, `-X ours` and `-X theirs`, *do not* affect high level conflicts.

<sup>3</sup>You can use `-X ours` or `-X theirs` to make Git choose "our change" or "their change" instead of stopping with a conflict.  Note that you specify this as an argument to `git merge`, so it applies to *all* files that have conflicts.  It's possible to do this one file at a time, after the conflict happens, in a more intelligent and selective way, using `git merge-file`, but Git does not make this as easy as it should.

<sup>4</sup>At least, Git *thinks* the file is successfully merged.  Git is basing this on nothing more than *the two sides of the merge touched different lines of the same file and that must be OK*, when that's not necessarily actually OK at all.  It works pretty well in practice, though.

<sup>5</sup>Some people prefer *merge tools*, which generally show you all three of the input files and allow you to construct the correct merge result somehow, with the *how* depending on the tool.  A merge tool can simply extract those three inputs from the index, since they are right there in the three slots.

## How do `git cherry-pick` and `git revert` work?

These are also three-way merge operations.  They use the commit graph, in a fashion similar to the way `git show` uses it.  They are not as fancy as `git merge`, even though they use the *merge as a verb* part of the merge code.

Instead, we start with whatever commit graph you might have, e.g.:

```
...---o--P--C---o--...
      .      .
       .    .
        .  .
 ...--o---o---H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

The actual relationship, *if any*, between `H` and `P`, and between `H` and `C`, is not important.  The only thing that matters here is that the *current* (HEAD) commit is `H`, and that there is some commit `C` (the child) with a (one, single) parent commit `P`.  That is, `P` and `C` are directly the parent-and-commit of the commit we want to pick or revert.

Since we're on commit `H`, that's what is in our index and work-tree.  Our HEAD is attached to the branch named *`branch`*, and *`branch`* points to commit `H`.<sup>6</sup>  Now, what Git does for `git cherry-pick hash-of-C` is simple:

- *Choose* commit `P` as the merge base.
- Do a standard three-way merge, the *merge as a verb* part, using the current commit `H` as ours and commit `C` as theirs.

This merge-as-a-verb process happens in the index, just as for `git merge`.  When it's all done successfully—or you'e cleaned up the mess, if it *wasn't* successful, and you've run `git cherry-pick --continue`—Git goes on to make an *ordinary, non-merge* commit.

If you look back at the merge-as-a-verb process, you'll see that this means:

- diff commit `P` vs `C`: that's what they changed
- diff commit `P` vs `H`: that's what we changed
- combine these differences, applying them to what's in `P`

So `git cherry-pick` *is* a three-way merge.  It's just that *what they changed* is the same thing that `git show` would show!  Meanwhile, *what we changed* is everything we need to turn `P` into `H`—and we *do* need that, because we want to *keep* `H` as *our* starting point, and only add *their* changes to that.

But this is also how and why cherry-pick sometimes sees some strange—we think—conflicts.  It has to *combine* the entire set of `P`-vs-`H` changes with the `P`-vs-`C` changes.  If `P` and `H` are very far apart, those changes could be massive.

The `git revert` command is just as simple as `git cherry-pick`, and in fact, is implemented by the same source files in Git.  All it does is use commit `C` as the merge base and commit `P` as *their* commit (while using `H` as ours as usual).  That is, Git will diff `C`, the commit to revert, vs `H`, to see what we did.  Then it will diff `C`, the commit to revert, vs `P` to see what they did—which is, of course, the reverse of what they actually did.  Then the merge engine, the part that implements *merge as a verb*, will combine these two sets of changes, applying the combined changes to `C` and putting the result into the index and our work-tree.  The combined result keeps our changes (`C` vs `H`) and *undoes* their changes (`C` vs `P` being a reverse-diff).

If all goes well, we end up with a perfectly ordinary new commit:

```
...---o--P--C---o--...
      .      .
       .    .
        .  .
 ...--o---o---H--I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

The difference from `H` to `I`, which is what we will see with `git show`, is either a *copy* of the `P`-to-`C` changes (cherry-pick) or a *reversal* of the `P`-to-`C` changes (revert).

---

<sup>6</sup>Both cherry-pick and revert refuse to run unless the index and work-tree match the current commit, though they do have modes that allow them to be different.  The "allowed to be different" is just a matter of tweaking expectations. and the fact that if the pick or revert *fails*, it may be impossible to recover cleanly.  If the work-tree and index match the commit, it's easy to recover from a failed operation, so that's why this requirement exists.

Comment: Wow, what a hell of an answer! Too bad you can't give some special badge here for the stuff like this... Thank you very much!